# Share options not working in finder and after right clicking

Tags: macbook-pro, macos

Here is the description https://discussions.apple.com/message/29155662#29155662

This is what it looks like after I select any one of the options from share

[image]

Comment: Is the share option disabled for all your files ? what do you see when you go to Settings -> Extensions ?

Comment: @maetsoh http://imgur.com/cOmYquh this is what my extensions look like
and the share option in finder gets disabled and also I cannot go back in finder and also not able to close/expand/minimize the finder window, have to force quit.

Comment: have you configured , through settings, your iCloud account ? Facebook ? Twitter ? ... ? It may be the reason why sharing extensions aren't working. I can't figure out why finder grays the other file options ...

Comment: very weird behavior from Finder, I'm sorry I can't help you. I suggest an os x backup and reinstall.

Comment: Yeah I have configured but the problem is airdrop is also not working and we dont need any configurations to setup for Airdrop right?

Comment: this is all you need to configure in airdrop : https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203106